# What kind of bar is this and how can I add one?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I need to add a bar to the bottom of each screen in my app. It has to look very similar to this:

[image]

What kind of bar is this, and how to I add a basic one to a Xamarin.Android app?

Comment: to me seems the ActionBar.Tab

Answer (score 0):

This is a split action bar (or this should be implemented with one). Extract from [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar):

> When your application is running on Android 4.0 (API level 14) and
>   higher, there's an extra mode available for the action bar called
>   "split action bar." When you enable split action bar, a separate bar
>   appears at the bottom of the screen to display all action items when
>   the activity is running on a narrow screen (such as a
>   portrait-oriented handset).

Comment: Is it possible to get this bar to appear on the bottom only without requiring the UI to be too narrow, as specified with `uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"`? I'm not interested in having the buttons on the top.